# Swiper slider ignore custom settings

Tags: css, wordpress, swiper.js

I want to create a small swiper slider that will rotate some logo images with a scrollable horizontal bar. I have already done something similar without problems, but now I'm facing a problem with the integration of the slider. The images I'm using have different sizes, but I want to give them a fixed width and height of 80px. I've tried to setup this value from the css but the settings will be ignored, images will be stretched to 1280px width and it will fade in between the images and I don't want this beahviour. I have more than one swiper instance on the same page, but I don't think that this can be a problem because I've setted another class for the slider who are giving me the problem.
Here is the code I'm using:

```
<?php
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'post',
'name' => 'partners'
);
$logo_img = new WP_Query( $args );
?>
<div class="container" id="">
<div class="row" style="margin-top:1em;margin-bottom:1em;">
<?php if( $logo_img->have_posts() ): while( $logo_img->have_posts() ): $logo_img->the_post();
$logo_gallery = get_post_gallery_images( $post->ID );
if( $logo_gallery ): ?>
<div class="swiper-container partners-slider" id="partners-slider">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper" id="partners-logo-wrapper">
<?php  foreach($logo_gallery as $logo ): ?>
    <img class="swiper-slide partner-logo" src="<?php echo $logo; ?>" alt="" width="80" id="partner-logo"/>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
  </div>
  <div class="swiper-scrollbar"></div>
</div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    const swiperLogos = new Swiper('.partners-slider',{
      autoplay: {
      delay: 5000,
      },
      slidesPerView: 'auto',
      slidesPerColumnFill: 'row',
      scrollbar: {
        el: '.swiper-scrollbar',
        draggable: true,
      },
    });
</script>

</div>
```

### CSS

```
#partners-slider{
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: transparent;
}
.partner-logo{
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `.swiper-slide img { width: 80px!important; height: 80px!important; }`

Comment: I can't use this solution because I have other sliders and this will apply the settings for all the sliders because `.swiper-slide` is the main class applied to the images of every slider!

Comment: Did you try `.swiper-slide .partner-logo img { width: 80px!important; height: 80px!important; }`?

Comment: The images will disappear if i set `!important` on width

Comment: Why would they? Maybe there is a problem with a padding or a margin that you apply to the images?

Comment: The css I'm using for the images is in the question, so you can see that there isn't set any margin or padding. [this](http://idangero.us/swiper/demos/080-scrollbar.html) is the result I want but with multiple images per row.